# Who were Grindelwald's parents?

Tags: harry-potter, gellert-grindelwald

I was curious to know if Gellert had parents that were abusive or malnourished him (which may have influenced his life) and if they had criminal records or worked for the ministry?

Comment: Mr and Mrs Grindlewald, presumably.

Comment: :( not even a little mac?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very little (in fact practically nothing) is known about Grindlewald's parents. We can *surmise* that one or both of his parents were pure-bloods since he was described as having been educated at Durmstrang, which obviously doesn't permit muggle-borns to attend.

> **Educated at Durmstrang, a school famous even then for its unfortunate
> tolerance of the Dark Arts, Grindelwald showed himself quite as
> precociously brilliant as Dumbledore.** Rather than channel his
> abilities into the attainment of awards and prizes, however, Gellert
> Grindelwald devoted himself to other pursuits. At sixteen years old,
> even Durmstrang felt it could no longer turn a blind eye to the
> twisted experiments of Gellert Grindelwald, and he was expelled.
>
> Hitherto, all that has been known of Grindelwald’s next movements is
> that he ‘travelled abroad for some months’. It can now be revealed
> that **Grindelwald chose to visit his great aunt in Godric’s Hollow**, and
> that there, intensely shocking though it will be for many to hear it,
> he struck up a close friendship with none other than Albus Dumbledore.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sup></sub>

Beyond that, aside from the identity of his Great-Aunt Bathilda, we don't know anything else.